# Line search Armijo, Wolfe, Strong Wolfe and Goldstein.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

What are the articles (References) who proposed the line search of Armijo, Wolfe, Strong Wolfe, and Goldstein? Articles precursors of unidirectional searches?

Answer (score 0):

Goldstein strategy is proposed by A. A. goldstein in 1962:
《Cauchy's method of minimization》